# Не работает конструктор перемещения

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор, move

```
struct MyString{
    string data;

    MyString(string&& str)
    : data(std::move(str)) {
    }

    MyString(const MyString&) = delete;
    MyString& operator=(const MyString&) = delete;

    MyString(MyString&& other)
    : data(std::move(other.data)) {
    }

    MyString& operator=(MyString&& rhs) {
        data = std::move(rhs.data);
    }

};

int main()
{
    MyString a("one"s);
    MyString b({"one"s});
    MyString c{"one"s};
    vector<MyString>({{"One"s}, {"Two"s}, {"Three"s}, {"For"s}});
}
```

При создании переменных a, b и c - ошибок нет. А при построении вектора ошибка: "call to deleted constructor of 'MyString'". Почему так? Почему не используется конструктор перемещения?

Comment: конструктор перемещения тут не причем.

Comment: Почему не причем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::initializer_list` - параметр конструктора вектора - хранит константные элементы. Поэтому из такого списка они копируются, а не перемещаются.

Comment: А как решить проблему?

Comment: @Давид Не использовать такой конструктор вектора. Как вариант, `push_back`-ать элементы.